# Número de linhas MySQL

Tags: mysql

Gostaria de saber se é possível mostrar o número total de linhas de uma tabela ao dar um `SELECT` no MySQL Workbench (estou usando a versão 5.2.33), pois ele só mostra as primeiras 1000 linhas da minha tabela, tanto que ele fala que existem mais linhas disponíveis para visualização.

Segue exemplo:
[image: vejam só]

Obrigado!

Comment: @Sorack obrigado, deu certo!!